# Kibana restric accesss by index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have Kibana on Elasticsearch 7.10 (AWS), I have a scenario in which many users from different teams will access the platform.
My goal is to configure some roles such as each user from each team can access only a specific index pattern (created by Admin).

Let's say we have:

Teams:

- Team A --> must access only dept-A-* (index pattern)
- Team B --> must access only dept-B-* (index pattern)

Currently I have (ex: Role for Team A)

Cluster Permissions --> data_access (built-in)
Index Permissions --> .kibana, .kibana-6, .kibana_*, dept-A-*

A user with this role can view the logs, but can also access Stack management, settings and much more, that is not ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can control feature access [based on user need](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/xpack-spaces.html#spaces-control-feature-visibility) or [based on user privilege](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/xpack-spaces.html#spaces-control-user-access)

[image: Kibana privileges]

According to the Role Management [Feature Availability](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/xpack-kibana-role-management.html#_feature_availability) docs, disabling a feature at either the space or the role level would be sufficient to make it genuinely unavailable, not just hidden. If you're worried about clever users access hidden options, it might be worthwhile to confirm by testing that the features are genuinely unavailable. Or you could just disable at both levels.